# How to select multiple files by filetype and add extension in Terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript, command-line-interface

I have a Mac (OS Tiger!) - 50GB of files - many without extensions. Finder cannot identify them.

But I would like to be able to select all extension-less files of one type (eg. jpg, tif, psd, ppt, doc) in one folder (and subfolders) and then add the correct extension to all of them.

I have learned that I find the filetype and encoding of a single file by typing this in Terminal:

```
file -I path/filename
```

This just outputs the file type and encoding for one file.

I then need it to add the correct extension and automate it for every file with no extension, in all subfolders.

Comment: i get an error message when I type file -l filename.

Comment: You can find and loop through all the files without an extension by using `find . -type f ! -name "*.*"`, and the extension can be found by the command `file --extension file_name`. But, there is no guarantee for a suitable extension to be found .

Comment: Thank you BlackPearl. There is no dot “.” In the filenames as they have no extension, eg “photo”. Would “*.*” still work when there is no dot between the two * ?

Comment: Also how do I search by file type, eg. image/jpeg; ? I really then need to combine these and then add the .jpg to the filenames (for that example)

Comment: `find . -type f ! -name "*.*"` indicates that it finds all files which do not have a dot.